# Adding/sum the 'int' list from the database C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have applications in asp.net.

The following function gets a list for me

DniOdpracowania type: int  (in database/sql server)

**Controller:**

```
 var sth = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.Year == nrYear 
                                   && x.Month< nrMonth )
                            .Select(i => new { i.DniOdpracowania })
                            .ToList();
```

[image]

I have a problem, I don't know how to add such a list to the variable sthSUM

```
var sthSUM  =  .... ;
```

Should I use the 'Aggregate' function (I can't match it here) or something else?

Comment: `.Sum(x => x.DniOdpracowania )` what about this?

Comment: Do you want to store list of all `DniOdpracowania `? or just want sum of all `DniOdpracowania`. If you want only sum of all `DniOdpracowania`, instead of list then just replace `.Select()` with `.Sum()` in your first linq

Comment: Why not call `Sum(i => i.DniOdpracowania)` instead of `Select().ToList()`? The server can aggregate data a lot faster than the client. A simple `SELECT SUM(DniOdpracowania) FROM Karta WHERE....` is a lot faster than sending all rows to the client for evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
var sthSUM  =  sth.Sum(x=>x.DniOdpracowania);
```